# Writing on HDFS is resulting in 502 response

Tags: hdfs, gateway

I'm writing a text file on HDFS.

This operation is done every minute.

If 10 writings are tried, I get seven 502 responses, and three 201 responses.

This happens even though the same code is repeated.

What could be a reason for this??

Do I have to write less frequently??

Any thought appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Create_and_Write_to_a_File, there are two steps for this operation.

First, I have to get the location of the datanode, and then I can upload a file to the location.

I skipped step 2, and just tried to upload at step 1.

But this isn't supported in the system that I'm using.

So, I added step 2, and it works well now.